# How can I fix 503 (service unavailable)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**I deployed my reactApp with heroku successfully but my POST request can't be handled and instead am getting an error messages in the console when i try to submit the contact form ?**

*I have attached a screenshot for the errors logged in the console*

** package.json **in the client's folder

{
   "proxy": "https://localhost: 5000",
}

** **screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxP3.png)** ** 
// index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
// remove dotenv on deploy
//require('dotenv').config();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body)
    // console.log(process.env)

    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const htmlEmail = `
            <h4>Register as a software Engineer</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>First Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
                <li>Last Name: ${req.body.nam}</li>
                <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
                <li>Years of Coding Experience: ${experience}</li>
            </ul>
        `
        // let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();


        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
           service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              user: process.env.REACT_APP_FOO1,
              pass: process.env.REACT_APP_FOO3
            }
        });


        let mailOptions = {
            from: req.body.email,
            to: process.env.REACT_APP_FOO1,
            subject: req.body.name,
            text: req.body.email,
            html: htmlEmail
        }

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Message not sent !')
            }
            return console.log('Message sent successfully!' + info.body.email)
        })
    })
}) 

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening to port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: can you [check the logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#view-logs)?.

Comment: Hi @saurabh, yes i checked the logs and this is what i get here [2019-09-20T10:18:25.993744+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/form" host=skylla.herokuapp.com request_id=25dbe0cb-5d44-4e31-923e-1c92429f460c fwd="41.210.159.124" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https]

Comment: you are getting an H12 error these link might help you [link1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), [link2](https://help.heroku.com/AXOSFIXN/why-am-i-getting-h12-request-timeout-errors-in-nodejs)

Comment: Okay i will have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to your server-side code.somthing is going wrong in your server.js.please add some code. so, we get more idea what you are doing wrong in server.js.

Problem: There’s a request timeout (app takes more than 30 seconds to respond): code=H12 desc='Request timeout'  status=503 bytes=0

> Solution: Code that requires more than 30 seconds must run asynchronously (e.g., as a background job) in Heroku. For more info read Request Timeout in the Heroku DevCenter.

```js
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
        const path  =  require('path');
        app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{
            res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))
        })
    }
```

Use this insted of

```js
// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash Karena, noted, i will update my server.js code above in the next 2mins. Thanks

Comment: Absolutely yes !

Comment: It's alright let me adjust my code as suggested. Thanks

Comment: POST https://skylla.herokuapp.com/api/form 503 (Service Unavailable),                                              Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 503
    at createError.js:17
    at settle.js:19
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (xhr.js:60)

Comment: This is the error I get when i run "heroku logs"    [2019-09-20T10:18:25.993744+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/form" host=skylla.herokuapp.com request_id=25dbe0cb-5d44-4e31-923e-1c92429f460c fwd="41.210.159.124" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https]

Comment: Okay i will have a look. Thanks